# Build a cell reference without knowing Row # (number)

Tags: google-sheets

This can't be a more basic spreadsheet question but I have always been a SQL kinda guy...

How do I build a formula where a value will be pulled from another column on the current row. Can't be the conventional 'E2' because the current row might be 3.

The problem boils down to defining a formula where the `ROW` designator is relative. `$E2` works when the formula is evoked on Row #2 but fails when evoked from Row #3. I'm creating Rows thru the API - my code can't know what row number is being inserted.

Comment: You might want to state what program you're using.

Comment: googleDocs' spreadsheet but i'll eat my hat if it's different than excel.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The [`ROW`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093316?hl=en) function returns the row number of any cell or range.

The syntax is: `Row( reference )`  but if the reference parameter is omitted, it assumes the cell in which the Row function was entered.

This can be used to refer to cells using [`indirect`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377), for example `=indirect("C" & row())` refers to column C in the current row.

Answer (score 7):

`=R[0]C[-1]` would make sense but R1C1 notation isn't working in the [new version of Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3541068) except within the [INDIRECT(ref, FALSE) function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en), e.g. `INDIRECT("R1C1", FALSE)`.

So write:

```
=INDIRECT("R[0]C[-1]", FALSE)
```

Comment: Parameter separation would be through ';' not through ','.

Comment: @Jpsy Depends on your locale. It is `,` for some countries and `;` for others.

Comment: Whow @sandwich – that explains constant hassles I had with the docs. AFAIK even Excel has this difference depending on the locale. Surely a big problem for many users who run into this problem without understanding why their commands do not work as described in the docs. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 4):

The `$` in excel (and google doc's spreadsheet) is used to create absolute (non relative) references. In other words, `$e$3` will refer to e3 no matter where it is copied to, from anywhere its copied to. You must lock the column and row individually (or the other one will change).

Comment: Also applies to Apple Numbers.

Comment: [sry for the misclicks on the votes]  I'm looking for the Absolute Column Relative Row expression. Always want value of E from row relative to current row.

Comment: $e2 or whatever number you want there.

Comment: isn't '2' absolute? I need a way to specify 'current row'.

Comment: The 2 is not absolute, just the e is. The $ only locks the thing that follows it immediately, not the whole thing.

Comment: Is it behaving differently because I'm using it inside this: =hyperlink("http://incoming.mySite.com/ConfirmOrder/"&$H3; "Confirm Order") because, with that usage I'm always pulling the value of Row 3 no matter what row it's on.

Comment: In order to get a row other than row 3, this formula must be copied to a cell on row 4 say, and it then it will automatically change to `=hyperlink("incoming.mySite.com/ConfirmOrder/"&$H4; "Confirm Order")` Where as if it were copied to the next column but same row, it would not change at all.

Comment: So we get to the point in my revised question where these rows are generated via the API not interactively. thnkx much for the persistance.

Answer (score 1):

This actually works and doesn't change the offset when inserting or removing rows or columns. The reverence here gets the value from 3 rows up and 5 cells left:

```
=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("R", ROW() - 3, "C", COLUMN() - 5), FALSE)
```

Change the values after `ROW()` and `COLUMN` to +/- the offsets you desire.

I needed a lookup to a separate sheet based on the value in same row and one column to the left. My problem was that I wanted to cut and paste text for the formula anywhere in any sheet, row, or column and have it work the same.

This is the `LOOKUP` formula I wanted and am using currently with success:

```
=IF(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("R", ROW(), "C", COLUMN() - 1), FALSE) = "", "", VLOOKUP(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("R", ROW(), "C", COLUMN() - 1), FALSE), Lookups!$A$2:$B$20, 2, TRUE))
```

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
=R[0]C[-1]
```

The square brackets mean it is a relative reference. `=R1C1` is the same as `=A1`

this works in google docs, not sure about excel.

Comment: R[1]C[-1] does not = A1. Were you intentionally referencing a different cell with the usage of brackets?

Comment: typing =R[0]C[-1] in cell B1  is the same as typing =A1. In Google docs it will auto convert one to the other.